# Pass data from HTML data-* to CKEDITOR textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

i want pass data from html data-* to CK EDITOR , but i don't know to solve it.

my html :

```
<a 
data-content='MY DATA'
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-data">
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-data" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
</a>

<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" id="modal-data" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="block block-themed block-transparent remove-margin-b">
        <div class="block-header bg-primary-dark">
            <ul class="block-options">
                <li>
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><i class="si si-close"></i></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <h3 class="block-title">Form Articles</h3>
        </div>
            <form class="js-validation-bootstrap form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" id="form">
             <div class="block-content">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Content</label>
                         <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" style="width: 450%; height: 500px;"></textarea>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
```

I tried with this jquery, but doesn't work, here my jquery :

```
$('#modal-data').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var div = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var modal = $(this)
    $('.block-title').text('Edit Articles');
    var b = modal.find('#content').val(div.data('content'));
    CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData(b);
});
```

the value doesn't show if i use ckeditor, but when i tried with textatrea without ckeditor it's worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `setData` for cke

```
CKEDITOR.instances['content'].setData(b)
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! IT'S WORKED

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, you can thank me by accepting my answer